# Why isn't there any value for this variable in this jQuery code?

Tags: jquery

Consider:

```
var ret = { valid: true, message: "" };
var prtime = $(".ptime").val();
var ctime = $(".ctime").val();

if ($(prtime).length == 0 || $(ctime).length == 0) {
    ret = { valid: false, message: "" };
}

$(prtime).length
```

When I run this, I get 0, even when I fill some words in *prtime*. And when I do `$(".ptime").val()`.length then it shows me the length.

What have I done wrong with that code?

Comment: do you have some HTML to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prtime` is a plain string. Don't wrap it as a jQuery object.

To get the amount of characters in the string, have:

```
var myLength = prtime.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Use this way
var ret = { valid: true, message: "" };     
var prtime = $(".ptime");  
var ctime = $(".ctime");     
if ($(prtime).length == 0 || $(ctime).length == 0) {     
 ret = { valid: false, message: "" };    
}
```